# How does read from string in bash works?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line-arguments

I came across a command like :-

```
/bin/bash -c LOCALHOST:/path/to/script --argument
```

and it gives a error like `/path/to/script` doesn't exist,but `/path/to/script` exists.

I want to know how `-c` option works.

Comment: Why do you have `LOCALHOST:` in your command line?

Comment: `-c` isn't really necessary here. `/bin/bash /path/to/script --argument` would do the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

You have to do it like this

```
$ /bin/bash -c '/path/to/script --argument'
```

Inside these single quotes is basically the line you would write before you hit Enter.

Comment: When i did echo $LOCALHOST , nothing got printed.

Comment: I don't really know what you intend to do, what do you want to know? Nothing got printed, because `$LOCALHOST` isn't set. If you want to know your hostname, try `echo ${HOSTNAME}`

Comment: I checked echoing LOCALHOST ,nothing got printed. Only thing i am worried about is syntax of bash -c command.

Comment: I don't understand your problem, if you won't set the parameter ` LOCALHOST` yourself, it won't be set